# Geocoding for a directory

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I need guidance on how to approach this problem.

I have a local directory which listings with addresses. I have been able to add geocode the address and save the latitude and longitudes. So far, no problem.

Now when the user searches in the directory, he/she will type in an address and then search for listings. The problem is I will need to geocode the search term(it will be an address/part of an address) and then search for listings.

Considering that the free geocoding limit is only 2500 requests per day, I will run out of the limit very soon every day.

Is there any other approach to this problem?

Comment: You didn't mention the accuracy that you need in the geocodes.  Are you looking for rough area or are you doing precision sky-diving.  There's a HUGE difference in the lat/lon accuracy that you will get from different providers.

Comment: Just a rough location. For example, suppose I have a directory of hospitals. As a user, if I type an address I am in now, I expect the list of hospitals close by. For that, the website first needs to geocode the address entered by me and then find hospitals closest to me. I feel this approach is expensive. Are there any other smarter ways to do this?

Comment: You've got the right approach.  You will need to first establish a list of hospitals and geocode those addresses.  Then, as an address comes in you'll geocode it and then determine distance to each of the hospitals and display only the closest ones.  If you can filter the hospital locations to just the ones in the same state (or neighboring states) you'll save yourself some time in the proximity determination.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a different geocoder which doesn't have this limit.

For example there is [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) which uses data from OpenStreetMap. Although OSM's official Nominatim instance has a rather strict [usage policy](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy) because it runs on donated servers you can just use a different instance, for example the one run by [MapQuest](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/nominatim). And if you want no restrictions at all then you can choose to run your [own Nominatim instance](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation).

Answer (score 0):

Purchase a Maps API for Business License 
http://www.google.com/enterprise/mapsearth/products/mapsapi.html

Comment: Very expensive for a start up. I believe it starts at $10,000 per year

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with US addresses, [SmartyStreets](http://smartystreets.com) sounds like it might be a good fit. We specialize in address verification and standardization, and we also return geocoding data (lat/lon) along with 40+ other data points, should you need them. Our [Terms of Service](http://smartystreets.com/legal/terms-of-service) are pretty open, unlike Google's (which doesn't let you use the geocode data for anything other than displaying on one of their maps); so you would be able to store and use the lat/lon in your own application. We have a jQuery plugin that can handle the address at point-of-entry, or you could use our [API](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api) or our [Lists service](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-lists) (especially useful if you have an accumulated list you want to process up front).

Our service also has an autocomplete feature that could cut down the time your users spend typing in addresses.

Comment: I am looking at addresses around the globe.

My question was more towards whether it is the right thing to geocode each location address before looking up my database of listings. Is there any other smarter way?

For example, would it make sense to maintain a list of user entered locations for quicker lookup instead of geocoding them everytime?

Comment: I don't really have much useful advice as far as the best way to go about doing this (I'm not a programmer). But it sounds like Jeffrey has a helpful comment above on your question. It sounds like it would be a good idea to geocode the address as it's entered, then you can compare it to the geocoded hospitals, etc. in your listings to find the ones nearby.